# Codeigniter ion_auth redirects to ?auth/login loop

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm setting up `ion_auth` for the first time and when I click submit from the login screen, it redirects the URL from `baseurl/auth/login` to `baseurl/?auth/login` and gets caught in a loop. Any ideas why that question mark is appended to the front?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd bet up to 3 dollars that it has something to do with the code...which I can not see...

Comment: In config.php, $config['enable_query_strings'] was set to TRUE. I changed that to FALSE and it works now. I came across this solution while troubleshooting a similar issue with pagination.

Comment: Cool. FYI you will always get better/more responses here at StackOverflow if you include the code you are having trouble with.